# Inherited class event is not fired

Tags: vb.net, events

First of all, this is my very first question in this community. Please give me some advice if I did it in the wrong way.

I need a little bit help. I am actually working on a BMEcat class library, BMEcat is a data exchange format for electronic catalogs. Anything works fine, but I realized that there is a memory problem while processing very large files. Because of this, I want to send an event for any processed article/product instead of creating a huge structure in memory.
This is the point where my problem begins.

I have a class `CTRANSACTION`, from which the classes `CT_NEW_CATALOG`, `CT_UPDATE_PRODUCTS` and `CT_UPDATE_PRICES` are derived.

In the base class `CTRANSACTION` there is an event defined:

```
Public Event Transaction_OnNewArticle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ArticleEventArgs)
```

The class `CBMECAT` has the variable

```
Public WithEvents TRANSACTION As CTRANSACTION
```

and the event handler

```
Private Sub TRANSACTION_Transaction_OnNewArticle(sender As Object, e As ArticleEventArgs) Handles TRANSACTION.Transaction_OnNewArticle
    '...
End Sub
```

Because I cannot send the event `Transaction_OnNewArticle` from the derived `CT_NEW_CATALOG` class I let it call the `TransactionEventOnNewArticle` method instead, which is defined in `CTRANSACTION`. `TransactionEventOnNewArticle` then calls `RaiseEvent Transaction_OnNewArticle`.

Everything works wonderful, but the event `Transaction_OnNewArticle` is not fired. Is there a way to fix it?

```
Public MustInherit Class CTRANSACTION
    Inherits CBMECAT_NODE
    Public Event Transaction_OnNewArticle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ArticleEventArgs)
    Public Sub TransactionEventOnNewArticle(ByVal sender As Object,   ByVal e As ArticleEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent Transaction_OnNewArticle(sender, e)
    End Sub

Public Class CT_NEW_CATALOG
    Inherits CTRANSACTION

    Public Overrides Sub EventOnNewArticle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ArticleEventArgs)
        TransactionEventOnNewArticle(sender, e)
    End Sub

Public Class CBMECAT
    Inherits CBMECAT_NODE
    Public WithEvents TRANSACTION As CTRANSACTION  

    Private Sub TRANSACTION_Transaction_OnNewArticle(sender As Object, e As ArticleEventArgs) Handles TRANSACTION.Transaction_OnNewArticle
        'THIS method is never called - why?
    End Sub
End Class
```

UPDATE

```
Public Class CBMECAT_ELEMENT 
    Public Overridable Sub EventOnNewArticle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ArticleEventArgs)
    End Sub 

'Please notice that CBMECAT_ELEMENT is the base class of EVERY other class in the library. 
'There is a class CBMECAT_NODE, which represents every node of the BMEcat XML structure and is derived from CBMECAT_ELEMENT. 
'In CBMECAT_NODE is EventOnNewArticle called whenever an article is processed;

Public Class CBMECAT_NODE
    Inherits CBMECAT_ELEMENT

    Public Overridable Function CreateChildNode(ByRef Nodename As String, Optional ByRef Parent As CBMECAT_NODE = Nothing) As CBMECAT_ELEMENT 
        Select Case Nodename
            [..] 
            Case ELEMENT_ARTICLE 
                CreateChildNode = New CARTICLE(Parent) 
                Dim e As New ArticleEventArgs With 
                { 
                    .ARTICLE = CreateChildNode 
                } 
                EventOnNewArticle(Me, e) 
                [..]
```

UPDATE

```
Public Class CARTICLE
    Inherits CBMECAT_NODE
    Public Sub New(ByRef Father As CBMECAT_NODE)
    [..] 
    Public Overrides Sub Read()
    [..] 
    Public Overrides Sub Write()
    [..] 
    Public Overrides Sub Validate()
    [..]
```

UPDATE

Calling sequence:

CBMECAT_NODE.CreateChildNode calls CT_NEW_CATALOG.EventOnNewArticle <- OK

CT_NEW_CATALOG.EventOnNewArticle calls CTRANSACTION.TransactionEventOnNewArticle <- OK

CTRANSACTION.TransactionEventOnNewArticle fires Event Transaction_OnNewArticle
but this event is not received by the event handlier in CBMECAT

If I fire the event manually from a method in CTRANSACTION the event IS received by the event handler.

I also experimentet with AddHandler/RemoveHandler, but this also did not work.

Comment: Welcome to the asking-side of the community! :) - It's a bit difficult to see the full picture... Could you please update your question with the base class declaration of `EventOnNewArticle` and the part of the code that calls it?

Comment: Sorry, I don´t know how to add additional informations to the original question

Comment: There is an `edit` button in the bottom-left corner of your post that you can use. This applies to both questions and answers. :)

Comment: `CTRANSACTION` does not seem to inherit from `CBMECAT_ELEMENT`? And when creating the article element you call the `EventOnNewArticle` of the `CBMECAT_NODE` class, but I don't see an overridden version of the method in that class. Can I see the `CARTICLE` class as well?

Comment: Sorry, my posting was incomplete. CTRANSACTION and also CBMECAT inherit from CBMECAT_ELEMENT. I have added the structure of CARTICLE, but that is a data class only, there is no event handling.

Comment: This step is not correct: `CBMECAT_NODE.CreateChildNode calls CT_NEW_CATALOG.EventOnNewArticle` - `CBMECAT_NODE` doesn't call `CT_NEW_CATALOG.EventOnNewArticle` but `CBMECAT_NODE.EventOnNewArticle`.

Comment: I think you've overcomplicated things. Since you've declared the event in `CTRANSACTION` then you should remove `EventOnNewArticle()` from `CBMECAT_ELEMENT` and instead only call `TransactionEventOnNewArticle()`. This will avoid confusion about which instance you are calling as it forces you to call it from a `CTRANSACTION`-derived class or from the class itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Visual Vincent, for helping me to focus the problem and to solve it. In deed it was "a little bit" complicated.

Class CBMECAT had the following read method:

```
Public Overrides Sub Read()
    MyBase.Read()
    GetContent(HEADER, ELEMENT_HEADER)
    Select Case TransactionType
        Case TransactionTypes.T_NEW_CATALOG
            GetContent(TRANSACTION, ELEMENT_T_NEW_CATALOG)
        Case TransactionTypes.T_UPDATE_PRICES
            GetContent(TRANSACTION, ELEMENT_T_UPDATE_PRICES)
        Case TransactionTypes.T_UPDATE_PRODUCTS
            GetContent(TRANSACTION, ELEMENT_T_UPDATE_PRODUCTS)
        Case Else
            ReportError(ERROR_BMECAT_UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION_TYPE)
    End Select
    Validate()
End Sub
```

MyBase.Read reads the complete XML file and while reading it, the events should be fired. But at this moment the variable *TRANSACTION* is not assigned by it´s value. This is done by calling GetContent after the reading process has finished.

I have changed to:

```
TRANSACTION = New CT_NEW_CATALOG
TRANSACTION.Read()
```

Now all events are fired as expected.
I will remove *TransactionEventOnNewArticle()* from *CBMECAT_ELEMENT*. Thanks again, Vincent, for your suggestion. :-)

Comment: Thank you again, Vincent. :-)